# Nexus3: What happened to number to keep task cleanup functionality

Tags: nexus, sonatype

In Nexus 2.14, we had a task to cleanup a repo but to keep the last 20; Number to keep. In Nexus 3, we are able to cleanup older than the last 30 days, but it's important to us to keep at least the last 20 builds. Is there a new way to do this I don't see in Nexus OSS 3.2.1?

Comment: I can see the functionality there for snapshots, but I need for releases. CI builds war's numerous times a day. Each is a release candidate, so building as snapshots isn't really an option. That said, we want to purge if they are so  old, but we want to keep the last 20 builds.

Answer (score 0):

We have not built this for Releases as of yet. Pop over to our JIRA and let us know your interest: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS